# Green stuff from natural crystal

Tags: mixtures

I continuously soak this natural quartz (it is originally white) in basin of water and salt, it has a metal on it too.

What caused the green stuff?

How to remove it?

[image]

Comment: Looks like algae to me.

Comment: yes, it may be algae, how do you remove the algae?

Comment: What is the logic behind soaking it in water and salt.? Sound more like $Alchemy$ work rather than chemistry.

Comment: I'm studying the Raman spectra of quartz soaked in water salt to see if there is any changes without liquid immersion, the raman spectrum i got is this https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/8730/5FQzZB.jpg

Comment: What *on earth* gave you the idea that quartz could be modified by soaking it in cold water?

Comment: The green stuff in algae is chlorophyll. If you are able to get resonance Raman spectra of chlorophyll, you can be reasonably sure you have algae (going confocal on the surface would certainly help as well). As for getting rid of them, how about soap, water + elbow grease?

Comment: How did chlorophyll end up there? My Raman is 532nm laser. Can i do resonance Raman with it? How?

Answer (score 2):

Do you know the origin of the sample?  Prior to deposit into tab water, was the sample already this green (e.g., a photo taken with the same color temperature of the light source [use of a color checker is seldom seen, even in institutions dealing with optics]) back then as now or / and UV-Vis reflectance spectrum?  For me, it is unlikely such a hard material will pick up and incorporate easily dye at ambient conditions (temperature, pressure, reaction time of some days or even months).  Think about glass ware and optic lenses, for example.

If the green does not go away despite washing with soap and a brush (quartz easier scratches than is being scratched if in contact with many materials) and you have experimental evidence that it is quartz, *surprisingly**) -- according to Wikipedia -- it could be [prasiolithe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prasiolite), a rare variety of green quartz e.g., from Brasil, or Lower Silesia in Poland:

[image]

Worth noting the [Swedish edition](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prasiolit) extending sources of origin and showing, e.g. this

[image]

*If* still passing the tests till here, maybe there is something worth a spectroscopic check. E.g., Caltech moderates a spectroscopic [directory](http://minerals.gps.caltech.edu/index.html) about minerals and references to [quartzes of color](http://minerals.gps.caltech.edu/Refs/Refs-Visible/MQ.htm).  Since quartzes may be grown in the lab (green hinting for  [$\ce{Fe^{2+}}$](http://minerals.gps.caltech.edu/COLOR_Causes/IVCT/Index.html)?), perhaps the [Günter group](https://guenther.ethz.ch/the-group.html) at ETHZ previously collecting expertise to discern diamonds of natural and artificial origin could be of help.

*) No, I didn't study geology.

Comment: It is originally milky clear. Im sure of it.

Comment: Here is proof it's not within the crystal. This is a medallion also soaked in the water with salt for about 10 years. How do I remove the green? https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/1773/ZoS3tT.jpg

Comment: No. It was not green originally. I bought a lot of it before to investigate piezoelectricity. I sold them and retained it. It was soaked in water with salt for 20 years (I remembered now). It may just be algae which also got stuck on the metal. How can I remove all the algae? is it possible?

Comment: @Jtl The medaillon, _assuming_ it were wet metal, reminds a little to malachite and some copper plates exposed to weather (e.g. Bartholdi's Statue of Liberty) but it equally could be _plated_ copper with only a thin surface of copper on a magnetic metal, brass, or bronze.  Thus, because a remote diagnosis _via_ a photo is guessing only, I refrain from a recommendation.

Comment: @Jtl The condensers within the rotary evaporators catch algae on the inner side (where tap water flows), too to yield a greenish bio film. So we drain the water, dismount them, fill them half with diluted (about 5 to 10 vol%) of aqueous HCl and gentle shake them.  Because quartz will resist to diluted HCl, too, you may try this too (put on gloves and googles, fill a plastic jar with diluted HCl, _gently_ rub the wetted quartz with a synthetic brush.  Since the material of the medaillon is not ascertained, _I would NOT_ use the acid there.